# How to properly use location in background - app got rejected 3 times

Tags: geolocation, app-store, appstore-approval

My app got rejected by Apple three times, all with the same rejection letter, which is:

> We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include
>   functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This
>   behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We noticed your app declares support for location in the
>   UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but does not include features
>   that require persistent location.
>
> It would be appropriate to add features that require location updates
>   while the app is in the background or remove the "location" setting
>   from the UIBackgroundModes key.
>
> If you choose to add features that use the Location Background Mode,
>   please include the following battery use disclaimer in your
>   Application Description:
>
> "Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically
>   decrease battery life."
>
> For information on background modes, please refer to the section
>   "Executing Code in the Background" in the iOS Reference Library.

Now, as far as I know I am running on the background and "doing something"...
In my AppDelegate I have the following code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    if ([[launchOptions allKeys] containsObject:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] &&
    ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]))
{
    id locationInBackground = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey];
    if ([locationInBackground isKindOfClass:[CLLocation class]]) 
    {
        [self updateMyLocationToServer:locationInBackground];
    }
    else
    {
        //Keep updating location if significant changes
        CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.bgLocationManager = locationManager;
        self.bgLocationManager.delegate = self;
        self.bgLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        [bgLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
}
```

The AppDelegate also starts a location manager and makes himself the delegate.
Then, I have the following code for handling the location updates on the background:

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self updateMyLocationToServer:newLocation];
}


-(void)updateMyLocationToServer:(CLLocation*)myNewLocation
{
    //    NSLog(@"Updating Location from the background");

    NSString *fbID = [NSString stringWithString:[facebookDetails objectForKey:@"fbID"]];
    NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithString:[facebookDetails objectForKey:@"firstName"]];
    NSString *lastName = [NSString stringWithString:[facebookDetails objectForKey:@"lastName"]];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MY_SERVER_API", fbID, myNewLocation.coordinate.latitude, myNewLocation.coordinate.longitude, firstName, lastName];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    __block ASIHTTPRequest *newRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [newRequest setCompletionBlock:^{


    }];

    [newRequest setFailedBlock:^{

    }];

    //    [newRequest setDelegate:self];
    [newRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

I also put a disclaimer in my app description page:

> Intensive use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life. For this reason, MY_APP_NAME runs on the background just listening for significant location changes.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Doesn't a 'background mode' mean something that is still running after the user has exited out of the app?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper Thanks for telling me. Being fairly new to StackOverflow, I was not aware of this system.

Comment: @cgull I`m not sure. I mean, isn`t registering for location update good enough? Then when there is a new location, my app gets waken up into background active state, and then I have the chance to do something, like log my new location to my server. That's what I thought...

Comment: It sounds to me that they don't have a problem with you accessing the GPS in the background, but more or less have a problem with how frequently you do. Try either changing your application to check for location less frequently or add the battery disclaimer they suggested and see if they approve it.

Comment: great that you're making progress @niraj (:

Comment: I have the same issue , and I add the required disclaimer , it rejected again , do you solve this problem , and I must use the location in background , what can I do ? , The app rejected 2 times . Could you help me , Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: or in updateMyLocationToServer: You should check if application is in background state by eg.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground
```

And then if Your app is in background mode You should use eg.

```
backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                    beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
                    ^{
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
                    }];

/*Write Your internet request code here*/

if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

This way application should perform this task completely.

Comment: There is no point in trying to endBackgroundTask inside the expiration handler, it was already ended via expiration.

Comment: Listen to @malhal’s comment at your own peril! From Apple docs: *You should use this handler to clean up and mark the end of the background task. **Failure to end the task explicitly will result in the termination of the app.*** https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtask

Answer (score 7):

This question is old and already answered but you dont need the `UIBackgroundModes` key if you collect locations using the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` API

Comment: I got the same rejection as stated above but when I take out my UIBackground modes, my startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges never gets called and I see the navigation arrow in the system bar disappear. Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you make a new question with all the details of what you are doing and some code samples. The scope is too wide for a 500 character comment. If you post your question link here as a comment i'll take a look at it. It should be working for you. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges  don't require a background mode registration. Only continuous location changes do.

Comment: Why have you provide the exact same answer again (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690459/apple-rejection-because-uibackgroundmode-location), please reference your answer don't just do a direct copy. And comments remain from other answer. This isn't really much of an answer and it this case doesn't even answer the question -1