# Apple rejection because UIBackgroundMode = location

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, appstore-approval

I submitted an app which tracks the user's location (and sends it to the server) at some fixed intervals chosen by the user (5 min, 10 min, 30 min, 1 h). The app should work in background, too (sending the requests) and I have declared it as `UIBackgroundMode = location`. I am able to send the requests while in background at those fixed intervals. Apple rejected it, suggesting the following:

> We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include
>   functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This
>   behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We noticed your app declares support for location in the
>   UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but does not include features
>   that require persistent location.
>
> It would be appropriate to add features that require persistent use of
>   real-time location updates while the app is in the background or
>   remove the "location" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key. If your
>   application does not require persistent, real-time location updates,
>   we recommend using the significant-change location service or the
>   region monitoring location service.
>
> For more information on these options, please see the "Starting the
>   Significant-Change Location Service" and "Monitoring Shape-Based
>   Regions" sections in the Location Awareness Programming Guide.
>
> If you choose to add features that use the Location Background Mode,
>   please include the following battery use disclaimer in your
>   Application Description:
>
> "Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically
>   decrease battery life."

If I change significant location change and remove `UIBackgroundMode` key from `Info.plist`, the app will be killed in background and will wake up only if the event occurs. But I must send the request to server every 5 minutes for example and my app is killed in the background (let's say the user does not move and the event is not `trigger = no` requests are sent to server).

Comment: Is the 5 minutes really important to you? You can have the significant location change and still report the location to a server in background. Technically it's possible. Would that work for you? I think for Apple it would work.

Comment: Maybe you need to update the description and comments for reviewer? It seems to me the app was not well understood.

Comment: Yes, Sulthan, I think you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like apple's complaint is that your apple think that your app *doesn't need* to use background location. If what you're trying to do is legitimate - e.g. your user would expect the app to track them in the background and this is a useful thing to them - you could try explaining why location tracking is needed in the review notes.

Comment: To resolve I think I just need to add the disclaimer in the App description "Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life."

Answer (score 8):

To resolve you have to add the disclaimer in the App description in Itunes Connect "Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life."

Answer (score 1):

I think it is best to address these questions directly to Apple. I hope you did so. 
They are very good at communication, providing your response is professional and clear. As are your questions.

I find it hard to believe that anyone will be able to help you here.

Edit: Add description to your app. Be clear in your messages to the user and to apple reviewers. It seems to help a lot. Remember, they are people too.

Comment: Thanks, I already told my employer to send them a reply with some questions.

Comment: To resolve I think I just need to add the disclaimer in the App description "Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life."

Comment: I have also got the same problem. So did you add this line in your app description and your app was approved?

Comment: I do have the same problem. Were adding the disclaimer in the description helps app to get approved.

Comment: Cool Manhatan, good to hear.
If anyone found my answer helpful, please mark it as so.

Comment: I got same issue please tell me what to do? Does just adding disclaimer in app description helped with approval?