# iOS background location updates

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

I have created an app which uses location updates in the background. I have submitted my app to apple but it got rejected by apple on the ground that you are using location updates in background rather than using significant location update and shape based region monitoring. 
My app takes location updates and provided user with specific updates, which works perfectly for my scenarios and have made code to better save battery. With Apple's suggested approach the problem I'm getting with significant location update and shape based region monitoring is location accuracy. With significant location update I get events fired for all the region within that cell tower range or say 100 m - 3000 m rather than when user enters a region say lat long with 100 m radius. 
I've had many conversations with apple and they don't seem to care about the developers and new technologies they are creating. 
Is there any developer who faced same problem of using background location update to do something other than navigation and got accepted or has anyone used significant location update with shape based monitoring to provide precise updates with better location accuracy.

Any help is much much appreciated.

Comment: This should help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527935/how-to-properly-use-location-in-background-app-got-rejected-3-times

Comment: Did you try to add a line to meta like "Whew, it eats battery as an elephant"? That solved rejection for me. Or they insist on disabling full background updation due to "we don't think your app needs this, replace it or reject, desn't matter what you put to meta"?

Answer (score 1):

Varun welcome to SO community.

Here is some lines from docs
***Any app that requests background location services should use those services to provide a tangible benefit to the user. For example, a turn-by-turn navigation app would be a likely candidate for background location services because of its need to track the user’s position and report when it is time to make the next turn.***

So if you are using standard location service and whenever you get updates and you are not doing anything with that update (in terms of user not coding) then there are very high chances that Apple may reject your app, which they already did.

So what's the solution then?
1. Answer is try submitting the app with other approach.
2. Try submitting the app with other name :D

Solution Number 1. Instead of using standard services use significant location service  which gives the accuracy of around hundreds of meters say 200-1700 m and track if user is moving near to your spot or far away from your spot.

If user is moving near to your spot and user is around 500m (depends upon you) near to your spot just start standard location services and track where user is going if user enters you spot then show user "Catch you" or if user moves away from your spot (>500m) then stop standard location service and start significant location service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and appreciate your response. I get users location every so time and compare that location user specified location and if those location matches then throw update or else do nothing. Now apple says this is not the right usage of background location services and those should only and only used for turn by turn navigation. They (apple) don't seem to understand this logic and are adamant on not approving the app. do you think with option 1  using both significant and standard location services will help me get my app approved.

Comment: @Varun I don't think you have another option. But chances are high